# Passing Objective-C parameters to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

.Swift file

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Contacts

@objc public class TestPlugin2: UIViewController
{
    @objc static let shared = TestPlugin2()
    @objc func ReturnSuccess() -> String
    {
        return "Success!!";
    }

    @objc func CreateContact(fname: String, lname: String, pnumber: String, email : String)
    {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
        {
            let contact = CNMutableContact()

            contact.givenName = fname
            contact.familyName = lname
            contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:pnumber))]

            if(email != "")
            {
                contact.emailAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:email as NSString)]
            }

            let store = CNContactStore()
            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
            saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
            try! store.execute(saveRequest)
        }
        else
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

.mm file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "TestPlugin2-Swift.h"

#pragma mark - C interface

extern "C"
{
    char* _returnSuccess()
    {
        NSString* returnString = [[TestPlugin2 shared]ReturnSuccess];

        char* cStringCopy(const char* string);

        return cStringCopy([returnString UTF8String]);
    }

    void _createContact(const char* fname, const char* lname, const char* pnumber, const char* email)
    {
        //ERROR IS ON THE LINE BELOW
        [[TestPlugin2 shared]CreateContact:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: fname], [NSString stringWithUTF8String: lname], [NSString stringWithUTF8String: pnumber], [NSString stringWithUTF8String: email]];
    }
}

char* cStringCopy(const char* string)
{
    if(string == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    strcpy(res, string);
    return res;
}
```

I'm getting the error "No visible @ interface for 'TestPlugin2' declares the selector 'CreateContact'"

I'm new to Xcode and iOS development, I have been unable to find a solution and I've tried several ways of converting the const char* variables from Objective C to Strings that Swift func will accept, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason for using C-strings in Objective-C? Also, did you try to make your function `public`? Default access level is `internal`, setting just the class as `public` is not enough

Comment: Select "TestPlugin2-Swift.h" in the Xcode editor and choose “Navigate -> Jump To Definition,” then you'll see how the Swift method names are actually mapped to Objective-C.

Comment: C++ doesn't support Swift. I assume Objective-C++ the same.

Comment: @mag_zbc I'm a Unity3D programmer and from all the tutorials I have seen this is how a plugin is created, that is why I'm doing this the way I am, I just haven't found any tutorials that pass parameters through, so I'm not to sure how to do it. Thanks for the help i'll try that :)